# Installing different C compiler messed up system header files

Tags: compiling, c, gcc, linux-headers

Today I installed scc, which is a different C compiler. [(Link)](https://git.simple-cc.org/scc/files.html) After realizing that scc was not mature enough for my use, I uninstalled it.

Installing scc apparently replaced many C header files such as stdio.h, math.h, and the changed versions don't work correctly with gcc. How can I reinstall all my system's header files, or at least the changed versions? Does anyone know what package provides such files?

I'm on Linux Mint 20.

Comment: I think this will do : `sudo apt install --reinstall libc6-dev` (If you installed to PREFIX= /usr/ ) .......... (The scc Makefile is wrong : Line 13 must be `PREFIX= /usr/local/scc`.)

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall `dpkg -l '*-dev' | awk '/^ii/{print $2}'`
```